# Resized image uploading

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3, cdn, image-resizing

I am working on a Laravel application and at some point, when I allow users to upload their own images for different purposes, I want to generate resized previews for these images.

I am uploading all user content to Amazon S3 and the first thing I did about resizing image is uploading the original image, then went through a `foreach`, resized the image and re-uploaded it to S3.

As you can image, having 4 sizes for each image dramatically increases the upload time and is a performance concern for me.

Here is a code snippet that I use in my `upload` function:

```
$storageDriver = Storage::disk('cloud-storage')->getDriver();
$parentSuccess = $storageDriver->put("/$parentId", file_get_contents($file), [
    'visibility' => 'public',
    'ACL' => 'public-read',
    'ContentType' => $contentType,
]);

$ratio = $imageSize[0] / $imageSize[1];
foreach (self::IMAGE_SIZES as $size) {
    if ($size > $imageSize[0] || ($size / $ratio) > $imageSize[1]) {
        continue;
    }

    $id = DB::table('storage')->insertGetId([
        'content_type' => $contentType,
        'parent_id' => $parentId,
        'image_width' => $size,
        'image_height' => intval($size / $ratio),
    ]);

    $image = Image::make($file)->encode('jpg');
    $image->resize($size, null, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
        $constraint->upsize();
    });
    $image->save();

    $success = $storageDriver->put("/$id", (string)$image, [
        'visibility' => 'public',
        'ACL' => 'public-read',
        'ContentType' => 'image/jpeg',
    ]);

    if (!$success) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

(I know there is a lot of code not included, but it's not relevant).

What method would you choose for handling this in a more efficient way?

Comment: Hey Victor, you can generate resized images in real time using a service like [ImageKit.io](https://imagekit.io), Cloudinary, Imgix etc. I am the co-founder of ImageKit.

Comment: @manu4543 Hi, thank you! I am looking forward to using a homegrown solution instead of adding extra costs for the application.

Answer (score 0):

Had to implement something like this in my last project, I used Lazy loading. Upload the parent image to s3 and generate the thumbnails only when needed.

You can have the function `getThumbnails()` attached to the model that has image. The function checks if thumbnails have been generated for that model and returns it, else it generates them.

```
public function getThumbnails(){
    $thumbDir = "path/to/model/thumbnail/dir";

    //Check if the folder exists.
    //You can also double check if the directory actually has the thumbnails in it
    if(!file_exists($thumbDir)){
       $this->generateThumbnails($thumbDir);
    }

    //Return something
}
```

For more fun, you can be more specific and have a function handle each thumbnail.

```
public function getThumbnailX(){
    $thumb = "path/to/specific/model/thumbnail";
    if(!file_exists($thumb)){
       $this->generateThumbnailX($thumb);
    }
    return $thumb;
}

public function getThumbnailX2(){
    ...
}
```

Super fun, add it as an attribute of the model.

```
public function getThumbXAttribute(){
    return getThumbnailX();
}
```

so you can go ahead and call `$model->thumbX` whenever you need thumbX.

This reduces processing time and also the size of storage required as not all images may have their thumbnail generated.

Comment: I think you missed the point however. If I do this, the `GET` requests will take long because that's when the image is generated. The huge latency comes from the fact the we do not store any user-uploaded content on our own servers but on Amazon S3.